# How to format xmpp presence stanza to join a MUC room

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I'm trying to figure out how to format a presence stanza being sent to a room, and I'm not following the examples I've found online.

```
presence_stanza = f"<presence xmlns='jabber:client' from='{user_id}@conference.domain.com/{what_goes_here} to='{room_id}@conference.domain.com'/>"
```

In particular I'm unsure what the ID/string that follows the `/` in the `from` address.

For reference:

https://www.ejabberd.im/node/5189/index.html

[Ejabberd not sending presence stanza to other roster members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13305720/ejabberd-not-sending-presence-stanza-to-other-roster-members)

Answer (score 1):

You should read the Multi-User chat specification, especially the part that describes how to enter the room: https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#enter

The spec example is well commented.

You do not even need to set the from. The server will set it for you to your current session full JID.
The `to` needs to be a full JID including indeed the room_id, but also the nickname of your user in the room. It should be something like:

```
<presence to='{room_id}@conference.domain.com/{user_nick_in_the_room}'/>
```