# To join a room, what needs to be sent in presence stanza? I received many presence stanza's without nickname in from attribute

Tags: ejabberd, strophe

In older version of ejabberd and strophe, the user needs to send room/nickname in 'from'. But in the updated version of ejabberd, what needs to set in from attribute of presence element?

I sent from="123@conf.com/John" where 'John' is the nickname. I received many stanzas, but some of them are without a nickname. Instead, it has ID in number. Is there any reference for that number?

Is there any mechanism/config to get presence specific to a particular chat room in which the user is involved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format xmpp presence stanza to join a MUC room](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56464533/how-to-format-xmpp-presence-stanza-to-join-a-muc-room)

Answer (score 2):

As specified in https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#enter the FROM attribute of PRESENCE element must be the user full jid, and the TO must be the room/nickname.

Real example:

```
<presence id='42:841254'
    from='user1@localhost/resource1'
    to='room1@muc.localhost/mynickname'>
</presence>
```

Comment: Is from attribute is a concatenation of roomName and nickname?